# Add context to multiple Results from inner calls

Tags: error-handling, rust

How can I do some post-processing on a whole bunch of `Result`s? I had code like:

```
fn stuff() -> Result<Quux, Error> {
    let a = foo().context("stuff() failed")?;
    let b = bar().context("stuff() failed")?;
    let c = baz().context("stuff() failed")?;
    quux(&a, &b, &c).context("stuff() failed")
}
```

I wanted to get rid of the repetitive calls to `context()` and kludged my way to a version using an [immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression):

```
fn stuff() -> Result<Quux, Error> {
    (|| {
        let a = foo()?;
        let b = bar()?;
        let c = baz()?;
        quux(&a, &b, &c)?
    })()
    .context("stuff() failed")
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, making another function (or lambda like you do) is pretty much the only way to go.

If you really use this often, you could make it a generic function:

```rust
fn stuff() -> Result<Quux, Error> {
    with_error_context("stuff() failed", || {
        let a = foo()?;
        let b = bar()?;
        let c = baz()?;
        quux(&a, &b, &c)?
    })
}

fn with_error_context<T, E, F: FnOnce() -> Result<T, E>>(
    message: &str, f: F
) -> Result<T, E> {
    f().context(message)
}
```

There is also a [currently unstable feature `try_blocks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/try-blocks.html) that would allow you to write something like:

```rust
fn stuff() -> Result<Quux, Error> {
    try {
        let a = foo()?;
        let b = bar()?;
        let c = baz()?;
        quux(&a, &b, &c)?
    }.context("stuff() failed")
}
```